SUSE OpenSCAP cli using a tailoring file
I am running the following command:
oscap xccdf eval --profile xccdf_org.ssgproject.content_profile_stig --tailoring-file /home/sle.admin/ssg-sle15-ds-epri-tailoring.xml --results /home/sle.admin/xccdf-results.xml --report /home/sle.admin/report.html /usr/share/xml/scap/ssg/content/ssg-sle15-ds-1.2.xml
It runs and generates a report, but the customized settings in the tailoring file are not making it's way into results.
